# What is the .user.yml file? What is its purpose?

Tags: dbt

I'm starting with DBT. When I ran my project it created a `.user.yml` file. Its content:

```
{id: c8e8abd2-09a3-4699-b444-3ef7ee5b04e5}
```

It seems from [this github issue](https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt/issues/1645) that it's some kind of cookie, but I could not find any info anywhere on what its role is.

Can someone explain the purpose of this file? Should I add it to my `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just got answered on the dbt slack.

The file just contains a cookie for dbt's anonymous usage tracking. It happened to land in my repo because I placed my `profiles.yml` in my repo. (my credentials are in environment variables). But normally it's rather created in `~/.dbt`

Comment: should it be added in the .gitignore?

Comment: @lokeshjain2008 if it appears in your repo, yes you should gitignore it